# How to install Morfeusz2 for Python on Windows?

Tags: python, dll, egg

I'm trying to install [Morfeusz2](http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/index.html) egg for Python 3.7 on Windows, according to the provided [user manual](http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/Morfeusz2.pdf) (translated from Polish):

> The Python module can be installed with the easy_install command from the .egg file downloaded from the site (for the appropriate Python version). The .egg file also contains the Morfeusz library with the SGJP dictionary, so you do not need to install other modules under Windows for the use of Morfeusz exclusively from the Python level.

Unfortunately, installation fails

```
python -m easy_install http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg
Downloading http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg
removing 'c:\users\oem\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\users\oem\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg
Extracting morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg to c:\users\oem\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
Removing morfeusz2 0.4.0 from easy-install.pth file
Adding morfeusz2 0.4.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\oem\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for morfeusz2==0.4.0
Searching for morfeusz2==0.4.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/morfeusz2/
Couldn't find index page for 'morfeusz2' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or working download links found for morfeusz2==0.4.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('morfeusz2==0.4.0')
```

I thought installation errors can be ignored, but it looks like the mobule has been installed only partially. When trying to call it:

```
import morfeusz2
morf = morfeusz2.Morfeusz()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects-intellij\mysite\ingredients.py", line 4, in <module>
    import morfeusz2
  File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg\morfeusz2.py", line 28, in <module>
    _morfeusz2 = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg\morfeusz2.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_morfeusz2', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.
```

How can I diagnose and fix the root cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the quoted command you use the file morfeusz2-0.4.0-py2.7-win32.egg which would be correct for Python 2.7 (py2.7) but not 3.7.

Eggs for other versions of Python are available here: 
http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/
Newer versions will appear in analogous directories (replace 20181014 with the string representing the last Sunday).
We hope to update the download page to list all versions available, but that hasn’t been done yet.

Comment: Thank you! Additional issue was with "DLL is not a valid Win32 application", because the library was for 64bit, and I used Python 3.7-32bit version. Installing Python 37-64bit resolved the problem.

Comment: I would like to install this library using pip, however pip supports only sdist (for source distributions) and wheels (for binary packages), while it does not support eggs. Do you plan to support pip-compatible formats?